# Unable to find an element in react test

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, unit-testing

I have this failing test in my `React` application but I've no idea what it means:

> FAIL src/containers/Drivers/Drivers.test.tsx (13.442s)
> ● Drivers › select values for occupation and relationship

```
Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="driver-firstName0"]

[36m<body>[39m
  [36m<div>[39m
    [36m<h1[39m
      [33mclass[39m=[32m"a-heading a-heading--1 u-text--center"[39m
      ...
  [36m</div>[39m
[36m</body>[39m

  102 |     fireEvent.click(yesOrNoQuestions[0]);
  103 | 
> 104 |     const firstName = getByTestId('driver-firstName0');
      |                       ^
  105 |     fireEvent.change(firstName, {
  106 |       target: { value: 'Name' }
  107 |     });

  at getElementError (node_modules/dom-testing-library/dist/query-helpers.js:40:10)
  at getAllByTestId (node_modules/dom-testing-library/dist/queries.js:289:45)
  at firstResultOrNull (node_modules/dom-testing-library/dist/query-helpers.js:44:18)
  at getByTestId (node_modules/dom-testing-library/dist/queries.js:296:46)
  at Object.getByTestId (src/containers/Drivers/Drivers.test.tsx:104:23)
```

Can anyone advise what I might have dome wrong?

Comment: seems straightforward to me - you're looking for an HTML element with `data-testid="driver-firstName0"` but one doesn't exist. As to why that is, it's impossible to say without seeing your test and the component(s) it renders.